# C float decimal not being memorized

Tags: c, decimal

I have a piece of code that looks like this:

```
float nb = 100 / 42;
printf("%.2f", nb);
```

which I expect to print out `2.38`, but instead it prints out `2.00`.

The `42` is just an example. In the original code it's a variable.

Comment: Try `float nb = 84 / 42`...

Comment: `float nb = 100.0 / 42;` or `float nb = (float)100 / 42;`

Comment: Here's a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602827/what-is-the-behavior-of-integer-division-in-c

Comment: why the down vote the user is new here ?

Comment: Memorized? Whatcha mean? And what "float decimal"? Both 100 and 42 are int literals.

Comment: @Engine - it's just those that lack the integrity to help others learn by explaining there down-votes. We could all benefit from understanding had the down-vote been explained. Unfortunately, the down-vote is all too frequently used by those who feel their important down-vote says it all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the numbers as floating point themselves. Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    float nb = 100.0/42.0;
    printf("%.2f\n", nb);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that `100.0/42.0` is a `double`, which is then downcast to `float`, and then upcast back to `double` for `printf()`.  So the conversion may be unnecessary.